My husband is Gay and he is active in sexual acts with other men, Can i divorce him
After three years of marriage and a 2yr old daughter i found out my husband is gay furthermore i found solid proof that he is presently im sexual acts with other men. Can i divorce him?

You can ask for khula.

Salam and welcome to IslamSE the Q&A site about Islam. To learn more about our site and the SE model consider taking the [tour] and checking our [help].

Salamalaykum sister, as much as I know yes your nikah is breached almost and you can't divorce him don't ever think something like that Allah created both men and women in different form and given them their life and tests and aspects to test upon and they have different ways to achieve the taqwa of Allah azzawajal so being women you should always have to obey Allah's law and follow the commands which has been revealed by Allah and by his holy prophet SAW, and the better option is a matter known as khula as it is totally lawful for you to take khul' from your nearby islamic court or seminary through a proper scholar 'ulema or 'aalim and they will support you undoubtedly because everything that Allah has initiated for humans has a purpose and your nikah was totally a lie and purposeless which was a kind of blunder but still you can't divorce him since it is not for women as Allah doesn't burden a soul more than it can bear and khul' nearby islamic seminary court or markaz from 'aalim is pefect, and may Allah Azzawajal make it easy for you, ameen. And rest Allah knows best.

Try using more punctuation marks for better readability. Thanks
